# Версия python3.7.4 не работает в Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

У меня возникает проблема. Создаю окружение. Активирую его. И пытаюсь установить любой пакет. Например, `numpy`. Возникает проблема: падает с ошибкой. При этом, первое, что бросается в глаза:

> 7.4.0 Collecting numpy   Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/32/1b8f2bb5fb50e4db68543eb85ce37b9fa6660cd05b58bddfafafa7ed62da/numpy-1.17.0.zip
>   Building wheels for collected packages: numpy   Building wheel for
>   numpy (setup.py) ... \

Какая-то версия 7.4.0. WTF? Если я сделаю deactivate, то всё отлично. В базовом окружении анакоды всё получается установить. Главное отличие: 7.4.0 первым сообщением не выводится. Всё работает, т.е. если я буду в окружении  Анакоды (base). Если же сделать новое окружение, то можно будет увидеть то, что я привожу ниже.

Вываливается огромный лог. Он очень большой. Приведу часть его:

> ```
> writing numpy.egg-info/PKG-INFO   writing dependency_links to
> numpy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt   writing entry points to
> numpy.egg-info/entry_points.txt   writing top-level names to
> numpy.egg-info/top_level.txt   writing manifest file
> 'numpy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'   reading manifest file
> 'numpy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'   reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
> no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'   no
> previously-included directories found matching 'doc/source/generated' 
> no previously-included directories found matching 'benchmarks/env'  
> no previously-included directories found matching 'benchmarks/results'
> no previously-included directories found matching 'benchmarks/html'  
> no previously-included directories found matching 'benchmarks/numpy'  
> warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere
> in distribution   warning: no previously-included files matching
> '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution   warning: no
> previously-included files matching '*.swp' found anywhere in
> distribution   warning: no previously-included files matching '*.bak'
> found anywhere in distribution   warning: no previously-included files
> matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution   warning: no
> previously-included files found matching 'LICENSES_bundled.txt'  
> writing manifest file 'numpy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'   Copying
> numpy.egg-info to
> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/numpy-1.17.0-py3.7.egg-info   running
> install_scripts   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>     File "/tmp/pip-install-0vsdxyrk/numpy/setup.py", line 443, in <module>
>       setup_package()
>     File "/tmp/pip-install-0vsdxyrk/numpy/setup.py", line 435, in setup_package
>       setup(**metadata)
>     File "/tmp/pip-install-0vsdxyrk/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 171, in setup
>       return old_setup(**new_attr)
>     File "/home/eurvanov/anaconda3/envs/grader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py",
> line 145, in setup
>       return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
>     File "/home/eurvanov/anaconda3/envs/grader/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py",
> line 148, in setup
>       dist.run_commands()
>     File "/home/eurvanov/anaconda3/envs/grader/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py",
> line 966, in run_commands
>       self.run_command(cmd)
>     File "/home/eurvanov/anaconda3/envs/grader/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py",
> line 985, in run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()
>     File "/home/eurvanov/anaconda3/envs/grader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py",
> line 230, in run
>       impl_tag, abi_tag, plat_tag = self.get_tag()
>     File "/home/eurvanov/anaconda3/envs/grader/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py",
> line 179, in get_tag
>       assert tag == supported_tags[0], "%s != %s" % (tag, supported_tags[0])   AssertionError: ('cp37', 'cp@pyvernodots@m',
> 'linux_x86_64') != ('cp37', 'cp@PYVERNODOTS@m', 'linux_x86_64')  
> ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy   Running setup.py clean for numpy   ERROR: Complete
> output from command /home/eurvanov/anaconda3/envs/grader/bin/python -u
> -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-0vsdxyrk/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> clean --all:   ERROR: Running from numpy source directory.
>      `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:
>
>     - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
>     - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
>                         files that aren't checked into the git repo)
>      Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).
>      ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy Failed to build numpy Installing collected
> packages: numpy   Running setup.py install for numpy ... done
> Successfully installed numpy-1.17.0
> ```

Внимание, обратите свой взгляд на строку:

```
('cp37', 'cp@pyvernodots@m','linux_x86_64') != ('cp37', 'cp@PYVERNODOTS@m', 'linux_x86_64')
```

Если она есть в логе, то скорее всего Ваша проблема похожа на мою

Comment: Проблема -- стопер. Тому, кто даст ответ, который полечит, 500 репутации через конкурс спонсирую. Конкурс можно открыть через 2 дня. Решение нужно сейчас.

Comment: @MaxU `pip install numpy`

Comment: @MaxU а какая разница, какие?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97393/discussion-between-hedgehogues-and-maxu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена. К сожалению, есть проблема с `python3.7.4`. Она известная и связана с `Anaconda` скорее всего. Вероятно, вы делаете что-то вроде:

```
conda create --name myenv python=3.7
```

Затем, вероятно, Вы делаете:

```
conda activate myenv
```

После этого устанавливаете пакеты:

```
pip install numpy
```

Тогда Вы получаете ошибку в духе:

```
  AssertionError: ('cp37', 'cp@pyvernodots@m', 'linux_x86_64') != ('cp37', 'cp@PYVERNODOTS@m', 'linux_x86_64')

  ERROR: Complete output from command /home/eurvanov/anaconda3/envs/grader/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7_9eghul/tornado/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-yw_kkztt --python-tag cp37:
```

Или вывод непонятного сообщения в лог в большом объёме. В частности, у меня это проблема с tornado почему-то. У меня много вот таких сообщений:

```
  copying tornado/tcpserver.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/concurrent.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/_locale_data.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/websocket.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/template.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/gen.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/web.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/netutil.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/routing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/iostream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/httpclient.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/ioloop.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/wsgi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/locale.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/escape.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/options.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/simple_httpclient.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/autoreload.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/tcpclient.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/curl_httpclient.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/httputil.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/process.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/auth.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/testing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/queues.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/http1connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/httpserver.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/log.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  copying tornado/locks.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado/test
  copying tornado/test/httpserver_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado/test
  copying tornado/test/testing_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado/test
  copying tornado/test/tcpserver_test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/tornado/test
```

Всё, что Вам нужно сделать -- это указать предыдущую минорную версию:

```
conda create --name myenv python=3.7.3
```

Тогда всё заработает. Вот [здесь](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164703/installing-openexr-for-python-causes-setuptools-to-fail-with-an-assertion-error) люди также обсуждают такую проблему

Хороший критерий, чтобы понять, что Ваша проблема такая же, как и эта:

```
('cp37', 'cp@pyvernodots@m','linux_x86_64') != ('cp37', 'cp@PYVERNODOTS@m', 'linux_x86_64')
```

Если такая строка есть в логе, то скорее всего здесь представлено решение Вашей проблемы